# Blazor (server) - Redirection to another page that depends user status and page attribute

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Currently, I have such code at MainLayout.razor file. That is redirecting the request to any page to the Register page if a user is not logged. That is working quite well still I have two issues with that.

```
protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    var user = (await AuthStat).User;
    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Register");
    }
}
```

1. User is redirected to Identity/Account/Register even if he/she tries to access the page that has AllowAnonymous attribute.
2. That is not a problem, still, I'm curious why any request to a page other than Identity/Account/Register is redirected to Identity/Account/Register. All except Identity/Account/Login. That is how it should be still I don't know why that works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use like this

```
<AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin></RedirectToLogin>
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
```

[full article](https://blog.vfrz.fr/blazor-redirect-non-authenticated-user/) is here.